# How a wireless access point reads all the available SSIDs

Tags: wireless, network, access-point

When a wireless access point is broadcasting its SSID (beacon frame) I assume it sends it on specific selected channel (channel 1-14 for 2.4 GHz network).

But how do all the other access point receive it? Do they make a frequency sweep to look at all the channels to read the beacon frames?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A WAP doesn't care about other WAPs. SSIDs are broadcasted on the channel that the WAP is configured to use. It's up to a client to find the WAP it's looking for.

*Some* WAPs support automatic channel selection and actually scan the band for already used channels, but that's not standard (more common on consumer-grade, off-topic devices).

Comment: But then the client needs to make a channel sweep from 1-14 continuously and look what SSIDs that are broadcasted?

Comment: @Hulla Yes, the client needs to scan when it's not connected yet.